# Как массив вставить в свойство обьекта

Tags: javascript

Есть объект(eventData) с двумя свойствами, так же есть 2 массива значения в них всегда разные и разное кол-во, могут быть вообще пустыми зависит от того сколько пользователь картинок закинет и потом сколько удалит. Вопрос как в свойство объекта передать значения массивов. Так как я делаю не подходит из за запятой в начале.

```js
var eventData = {saveImageId: '', deleteImageId: ''};

var allImageEvent = [{id: "3e6392d7-1ec0-43bc-bde8-bfae8a0887aa", 
value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…VVySbWvf2SXF3Oq1gNBSv2+Vem1lJBCmifYPt4kV/ydf/2Q=="},
{id: "51ad0373-9ff1-4db1-9cbf-1d45a1347c67", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…bl4H6AKy8iwzqRxxEgt7SG+Rbl0khBq2g+kgHxPEfpXH/2Q=="},
{id: "0fed717d-443f-46ac-9005-167e7b12a2d4", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…Habawvo3iXuK5zjgP2Ur1uaO3e1+rVNJrQkYJ+37P8v29f//Z"}]

var allRemoveEvent = [{id: "f3bd19d7-883a-4a85-afc8-6efcc6b4a4c5", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…Habawvo3iXuK5zjgP2Ur1uaO3e1+rVNJrQkYJ+37P8v29f//Z"},
{id: "9baf0323-0ee7-4f09-92ee-47bcc244b53f", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…Habawvo3iXuK5zjgP2Ur1uaO3e1+rVNJrQkYJ+37P8v29f//Z"}]

for(var i = 0; self.allImageEvent.length > i; i++){
                eventData.saveImageId = eventData.saveImageId + ', ' + allImageEvent[i].id
              }
              for(var i = 0; self.allRemoveEvent.length > i; i++){
                eventData.deleteImageId = eventData.deleteImageId + ', ' + allRemoveEvent[i].id
              }
              
console.log("save"+ "-" + eventData.saveImageId);
console.log("del" + "-" + eventData.deleteImageId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var eventData = { saveImageId: '', deleteImageId: '' };

var allImageEvent = [
  { id: "3e6392d7-1ec0-43bc-bde8-bfae8a0887aa", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…VVySbWvf2SXF3Oq1gNBSv2+Vem1lJBCmifYPt4kV/ydf/2Q=="},
  { id: "51ad0373-9ff1-4db1-9cbf-1d45a1347c67", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…bl4H6AKy8iwzqRxxEgt7SG+Rbl0khBq2g+kgHxPEfpXH/2Q==" },
  { id: "0fed717d-443f-46ac-9005-167e7b12a2d4", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…Habawvo3iXuK5zjgP2Ur1uaO3e1+rVNJrQkYJ+37P8v29f//Z" }
];

var allRemoveEvent = [
  { id: "f3bd19d7-883a-4a85-afc8-6efcc6b4a4c5", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…Habawvo3iXuK5zjgP2Ur1uaO3e1+rVNJrQkYJ+37P8v29f//Z" },
  { id: "9baf0323-0ee7-4f09-92ee-47bcc244b53f", value: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD…Habawvo3iXuK5zjgP2Ur1uaO3e1+rVNJrQkYJ+37P8v29f//Z" }
];

eventData.saveImageId   = allImageEvent.map(item => item.id).join(", ");
eventData.deleteImageId = allRemoveEvent.map(item => item.id).join(", ");

console.log("save-" + eventData.saveImageId);
console.log("del-" + eventData.deleteImageId);
```